# Why is ClusterRole allowed to list_pod_for_all_namespaces() but not read_namespaced_pod_status

Tags: python, kubernetes

I'm using Python 
and want to be able to check the status of a pod with:

```
kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api().read_namespaced_pod_status(name=name, namespace='default')
```

but this give my a forbidden, 403 response,
while:

```
kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api().list_pod_for_all_namespaces()
```

works fine.
The rights I have setup in a ClusterRole looks like this:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions"]
  resources: ["pods", "services", "ingresses"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "delete"]
```

So what do I need to modify to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pod's status is a sub-resource of the ["pod"] resource, so you have to define it for your ClusterRole as follows:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions"]
  resources: ["pods","pods/status" "services", "ingresses"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "delete"]
```

Comment: Great, thank you, that was it, but I must say that it is a bit confusing that you can get all of the status by list_pod_for_all_namespaces() without this permission.